# How to set a value programatically from resources string?

Tags: java, android

Lets say we have something like this in strings.xml:

```
<string name=“hello”>Hello world</string>
```

Now I want to set a value to a TextView using this string. Should I do it in java class like this:

```
TextView msgTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
msgTextView.setText(R.string.hello);
```

or in xml file like below?

```
android:text="@string/hello"
```

Which approach is better? Or when it is better to use the first way and when the second one?

Comment: Technically there wont be much difference in performance on either cases.

Answer (score 1):

You should do neither. There is relatively new approach , called databinding (it was demo in 2015) and now this library is officially supported by Google. It is a manifestation of MVVM pattern and you should use it, because it limplifies your code and makes it more maintainable in long term. See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html . In few words- you create Java class with fields and accessirs and set its fields as xml attributes. By doing so, AndroidStudio will generate all .findViewbyId() boilerplate for you. you just create model and set it to that particular binding.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding performance, it won't make any difference. I personally prefer to do it in XML, since it doesn't clutter your activity code.

Answer (score 0):

Both approach is correct. If you want to internationalize your variable that time (change languages)  both will be work. In reference of memory or speed dynamically change is correct(means using getResource() or R.string.hello).

Answer (score 0):

at first you should set it in xml.(or leave it empty.) but if you want to change it when something else happens (for example when user click a button or anything else.) you should set it in java.

Answer (score 0):

First method is generally used when you want your textview to be fixed and final .
Second method is recommended as the textview's value may change during the course of operation of app .Initially in second method , a value is shown by textview which shows its purpose or type . For e.g second one may be used in displaying progress of background task .